# How to assign admin role to a user in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am working on a website where I have student guardian relationships. So when a guardian is visiting his student profile, he should be able to edit, delete all the fields that a user itself can do. I am using buddypress and have used rtmedia plugin. Now For example, student uploads media, images. By default, other user can't delete or edit the media. But in my case, guardian should be capable of editing and deleting students media. I am thinking that if I assign the admin role to guardian when he is viewing students profile then my problem can be solved. But I don't know how to assign a user amdin role. Thanks

Comment: I changed this condition for upload button  bp_displayed_user_id() == get_current_user_id() and modified it for guardian. Now when guardian view students profile, The upload button is visible but its not working. Upon click, nothing happens. Then I just copied and paste html for edit, delete and upload button. By doing this, guardian can edit media, but when guardian wants to delete something, this message appears "Ooops !!! Invalid access. No nonce was found !!".

Comment: Now guardian is able to edit and delete media but can't upload..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading up on the User admin screen in the WordPress codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Users_Screen#Change_Roles_to

It explains how to switch roles for existing users, as well as assigning roles to existing ones:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Users_Add_New_Screen

Comment: In this link, user has to give role manually. I need this functionality in code so that when a guardian is visiting only his student profile then he should be capable of editing his student profile and if he is viewing any other user's profile then should not have this authority. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to give them an admin *role*.

You want to check for a student/guardian relationship and if found allow edit access.

To allow such access, you'll have to do various operations, for example, in BP, filter the profile screens loop  to allow editing.

Comment: thanks for this guidance. Can you tell me how to filter profile screens loop? Can you tell me a code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create php file to plugins directory and add below content

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Add role */
function add_roles() {
$result = add_role(
    'admin',
    __( 'Admin' ),
    array(
    'edit_posts'   => true,   // true allows this capability
        'read'         => true, 
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
        )
);
if ( $result !== null ) {
    echo 'New role created';
}
else {
    echo 'Role already exists..';
}

   }
   register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'add_roles' );
```

Above more capabilities can be added accordingly

More about capabilities at http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/wordpress-roles-and-capabilities-the-basics--wp-25921

Activate plugin and check under users to assign admin role

for guardian role assign capabilities to delete or edit the media.

For guardian (after visiting his student profile to edit or delete all the fields that a user itself can do) assign admin role and assign capabilities same as student by editing capabilities of plugin.
Then after reactivate plugin.